# Defining an ElasticSearch index with documents in multiple languages

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I am trying to migrate a MongoDB database which has [documents in multiple languages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/#create-a-text-index-for-a-collection-in-multiple-languages) to ElasticSearch. MongoDB support this by having an additional field which tells which language the sub-document is in. Example:

```
{
   _id: 1,
   language: "portuguese",
   original: "A sorte protege os audazes.",
   translation:
     [
        {
           language: "english",
           quote: "Fortune favors the bold."
        },
        {
           language: "spanish",
           quote: "La suerte protege a los audaces."
        }
    ]
}
```

I am unable to find a way to support this in ElasticSearch. It seems I can specify language only per field, but that language cannot be based on another field. Or am I mistaken? Is there a way to support this? If not, what would be the most suitable document schema for ElasticSearch for the example above?

Answer (score 1):

The same is available in elasticsearch known as [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#_multi_fields_with_multiple_analyzers). So for your example, you need to define the index-mapping as

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "text": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "english": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "english"
                    },
                    "spanish": { --> this sub-field will have Spanish content, which spanish inbuilt analyzer
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "spanish"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you can find [all the language supported](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html) in elasticsearch.

You can query multiple language-specific fields

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "quick brown foxes",
      "fields": [ 
        "text",
        "text.english" --> query english sub-field
        "text.spanish" --> query spanish sub-field
      ],
      "type": "most_fields" 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm, I do not see how this answers the question where I have data structured as described. So the issue is that `translation` is an array of objects and each object has its own language, so it requires a different analyzer. Your answer does not touch this at all.

Comment: @Mitar thanks for your update, If you notice carefully,  `text` has two subfields(english and Spanish and they use their own analyzer) and you can add as many as language fields, and their language analyzer (supported by elasticsearch, link of which also I provided)

Comment: @Mitar,  if you still have doubts, please read the official docs mentioned in my link, this would make it more clear, and feel free to ask follow-up question

Comment: Yea, I have read it. Your solution works for when the original document looks like `{"text": "content"}` and that `"content"` might be in different languages. This is not the structure I have. I have an array with sub-documents, where each sub-document has exactly known language, which is stored in a field.

Comment: @Mitar, yeah I get it, its just the difference in the structure, and you can make it work with you data-type(concept is important ), you can model the data according to your need. Hope you understand the point

Comment: @Mitar lmk if you have followup questions

Comment: Thank you. It is interesting answer, but does not really answer my question based on provided data structure, but answers a related question of how to have multiple languages indexed when data structure is not fixed.